# How to update a div in htmleditor

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

Could someone help me in updating a div in a htmleditor? Its in an iframe, so I could not do:

```
Ext.fly('mydiv').update('New value');
```

Right now I am updating the whole content with:

```
xtype:'textfield',
listeners:{
                keyup:{
                    fn:function(){
                        var e = this.up().down('htmleditor');
                        var v = 'some text <div id='mydiv'></div> some more text'
                        e.setValue(v);
                    }
                }
            },
xtype:'htmleditor',
...
```

where as I would only like to update the mydiv part only but cannot get reference to it somehow. Thanks.

Comment: We need to see your code. Consider posting an example or test case using JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi!jsfiddle.net unfortunately only has Ext core so I can not show an example there.

Comment: Well then, post an example someplace else. There's not enough information here to really diagnose the problem.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is this: I have a form with a textfield and a htmleditor as items in it. The editor has a preloaded pretty formatted HTML in it with a DIV where I want to put the invoice number, by typing it into the textfield above. Normaly I can update a DIV value with el.update(), but in this case the htmleditor is in an IFRAME. My temporary solution is updating the entire htmleditor value with every keyup event, but his is expensive instead of just updating the small DIV, but unfortunatelly I can not get hold of it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the real question here is "How do I access a DIV inside an IFRAME from its parent document?"

I haven't used EXT JS for anything, so I don't know its syntax.  But here it is in basic JavaScript.

First, the document in the IFRAME:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Child Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Child Document</h1>

<div id="stuff">
This is a div with some text in it.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And then the parent document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Parent Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     #iframe {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Parent Docment</h1>

<form action="" method="get">
    <p>
    <input type="button" id="get-it" value="Get It" />
    </p>
</form>

<iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframe"> </iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function getIt(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var stuff = innerDoc.getElementById("stuff");
    alert(stuff.innerHTML);
}

function init(){
    document.getElementById("get-it").onclick = getIt;
}

window.onload = init;

// -->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The key is this:

```
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

That lets you get access to the document object of the IFRAME, after which you can use it as normal.